# Use apache beam arguments within the pipeline

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

What is the best practice to get arguments from `pipeline_options`?

Dummy code example:

```
known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args()
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)


with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    # here I want to use project argument
    # I can't do pipeline.options.project 
    # because warning is displayed
    (
      pipeline
      | "Transformation 1" >> beam.Map(lambda x: known_args.pubsub_sub)   # this is fine

      | "Transformation 2" >> beam.Map(lambda x: pipeline.options.project)    # this is not fine
    )
```

How to use those standard arguments needed by pipeline (project, region etc.), not those user-defined?

Answer (score 3):

I think the best practice is using Options as follow, I kept your intial code :

```py
class MyPipelineOptions(PipelineOptions):

    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_argument("--project", help="Project", required=True)
        parser.add_argument("--pubsub_sub", help="Pub Sub", required=True)
        
my_pipeline_options = PipelineOptions().view_as(MyPipelineOptions)
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
    # here I want to use project argument
    # I can't do pipeline.options.project 
    # because warning is displayed
    (
      pipeline
      | "Transformation 1" >> beam.Map(lambda x: my_pipeline_options.pubsub_sub)   

      | "Transformation 2" >> beam.Map(lambda x: my_pipeline_options.project)    
    )
```

I think for predifined options like `project`, you have to add them in the `MyPipelineOptions` class to use it in your Python code.

Comment: Note that for user options, there's no advantage to defining a MyPipelineOptions subclass as opposed to simply using Python's standard `argparse` and `known_args` as above.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than accessing `options` via the pipeline object, simply use `pipeline_options` directly.

Comment: Can we recover default arguments like `project` with `pipeline_options` directly ? I tested it but it didn’t works.

Comment: You still have to use view_as, in this case via `pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)` https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.40.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py#L630

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers.

So your answers + Beam docs give me a full picture of options management.
To sum up:

1. If we need to define some additional, custom arguments (PubSub topic or whatever) we build simple parser using `argparse`.
2. Create `known_args` and `beam_args` objects from the parser.
3. `known_args` should be use in our Pipeline code directly (for example `known_args.pubsub_topic`).
4. `beam_args` are used to create `PipelineOptions` object which will be passed into `Pipeline()` object.
5. **[The most important for me]** If we need to use explicitly some argument that is already defined by Apache Beam (`project`, `streaming` etc.) we should not overwrite it in our custom parser - we should rather create `view_as()` object and use it explicitly (like `known_args`). Two examples below.
6. We want to use GCP `project` argument.

```
# "project" will go into beam_args because we didn't define it in our parser
known_args, beam_args = parser.parse_known_args()
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(beam_args)

# this argument will be available in "gcp_args" because GoogleCloudOptions class
# defining "project" argument (you can check source code)
gcp_args = pipeline_options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)

# and next if we want to use it somewhere we should do:
gcp_args.project
```

2. We want to use `streaming` argument.

```
# "streaming" will go into beam_args because we didn't define it in our parser
known_args, beam_args = parser.parse_known_args()
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(beam_args)

# this argument will be available in "std_args" because StandardOptions class
# defining "streaming" argument (you can check source code)
std_args = pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions)

# and next if we want to use it somewhere we should do:
std_args.streaming
```

So in fact in order to see which arguments are already defined by Apache beam we should see [Github source code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py)